# I can’t access my backend (Django/Python) from an expo React Native App (Android Device)

Tags: android, django, react-native, axios, expo

I built a simple backend with Django/Python, I’m able to access it from Postman, but when I try to access it from an Expo React native App I get a network Error

The way I test it is with my Samsung Android device

I’ve tried everything

From postman, if I send a get request like ‘http://127.0.0.1:8000/drinks/’, I get

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Grape Soda",
        "description": "Soda with Grapes"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Orange Soda",
        "description": "Soda with Orange"
    }
]
```

In the settings.py I have:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

From my Expo React Native App (ran on an Android):
I have an apiCall component:

```js
import axios from "axios";

export const apiCall = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/drinks/",
    timeout: 3000, // optional timeout setting
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
});
```

Using it from a DrinksScreen.js:

```js
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { apiCall } from "../api/apicall";

const DrinksScreen = () => {
    const [drinks, setDrinks] = useState([]);

    function loadDrinksData() {
        apiCall
            .get("/drinks/")
            .then((drinks) => {
                console.log("success!, data: ", data);
                return drinks;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("error!: ", error);
                return error;
            });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        let data = loadDrinksData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>drinksScreen</Text>
        </View>
    );
};
```

When I test it I get error!:  [AxiosError: Network Error]

What could it be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: your `baseURL` already contains `/drinks/` path, and are you trying to add `/drinks/` again after your `baseURL`?

Comment: Thank you for responding. I fixed it, but the problem still continues. I think that it is related with security. A local host being accessed by a mobile app, I have to do something else

Comment: what is your Django version?

Comment: Could you please share the status code when you send a GET request?

Comment: @Rafael, I have the same exact problem, were u able to solve it by now?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your laptop/computer and android device connected to the same network

Replace `127.0.0.1:8000` with your computer/laptop IP address, for example http://192.168.203.251:8000

Also tell Django to run on your IP address instead of localhost by running a command like this:
**python manage.py runserver 192.168.203.251:8000**